# How do I pass a unique identifier to a SignalR client/Server connection?

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I am looking at using Signal R for my system

Each user of my system watches a small set of data.

For example, Fred smith (UserID 1) may want to know the price of Gold

UserID 2 wants to know the price of Gold and Silver

Throughout the day there will be hundreds of prices passing through the market

As a new price comes through my system, I am thinking of looking at the users logged in and seeing if any of them care about the price that has come in

If the user cares, I want to send the price to the client instance

I dont want to notify all Signal R clients when every price comes in as that would be too much data!

I am assuming this relies on being able to store something generated client side then passing it through with the connection to the hub

Does Signal R support this?  I cant see anything obvious?

I have complete control over my hub.

At present, I plan to write data into a database which I use SQL dependancy to trigger the hub into action

I am using Signal R within MVC 5

Cheers

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Possiblity A) Use Groupping mechanisme of signalR**

- I suggest you to create a group for each "item" (gold, silver,....). 
  In the case a user logs in, you should look in which items he is
  interested and subscribe for these groups.

  (`Groups.Add(...)` in your hub methode)
- So in the case a the value of a item changes, you can send the new
  value to all subscribers (clients which are interested to a group)

  `Clients.Group(groupName).newItemValue(YOURIDEMID, YOURNEWVALUE);`

More details about groupping with signalr you will find here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups

**Possiblity B) Handle by yourself**

- In the case a client connects to the server save the id of this client. Also go to your database and show the interested items for this client. --> Finally you should have a dictionary which contains the ids of connected clients (id) and as value a list with the interested items.
- In the case a value of an item changes you iterate through all connected clients and search clients which are iterested about that item. Finally send them the new value.